# Update row with maxdate where id from select and maxdate from select is given

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a select statement that returns a set of ids and a maxdate. Now, I want to update the performance_date in the invoices table with the given maxdate where the given invoices ids.

```
Select invoices.id, max(invoicepositions.performance_date) as maxdate
from invoices
inner join invoicepositions on invoices.id = invoicepositions.invoice_id
where invoices.performance_date IS NULL
group by invoices.id
```

(How) is this possible with MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your current `SELECT` query as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and `Join` it to the `invoices` table using `id`, and then update.

```
UPDATE invoices AS i 
JOIN
(
  Select invoices.id, max(invoicepositions.performance_date) as maxdate
  from invoices
  inner join invoicepositions on invoices.id = invoicepositions.invoice_id
  where invoices.performance_date IS NULL
  group by invoices.id
) AS dt 
  ON dt.id = i.id 
SET i.performance_date = dt.maxdate
```